# python panda new column with order of values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make a new column with the order of the numbers in a list. I get 3,1,0,4,2,5 ( index of the lowest numbers ) but I would like to have a new column with 2,1,4,0,3,5 ( so if I look at a row i get the list and I get in what order this number comes in the total list. what am I doing wrong?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'list': [4,3,6,1,5,9]})
df['order'] = df.sort_values(by='list').index

print(df)
```

Comment: Why dont you just reset_index and you will have the index of the 'list' column within the list.


I mean you would have the indexes  = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 assigned to the values [4,3,6,1,5,9], this index would be the same as its list position.

Comment: I need the original index later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'list': [4,3,6,1,5,9]})

df['order'] = df['list'].rank().sub(1).astype(int)
```

Result:

```
   list  order
0     4      2
1     3      1
2     6      4
3     1      0
4     5      3
5     9      5
```

You can use the `method` parameter to control how to resolve ties.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for.